# Questão sobre operadores lógicos

Tags: c++

Queria saber qual é a resolução da seguinte questão:

> Em um cercado, há vários patos e coelhos. Escreva um programa que solicite ao usuário o total de cabeças e o total de pés e determine quantos patos e quantos coelhos encontram-se nesse cercado.

Já tentei de tudo quanto é jeito e não consegui resolver este problema.

Comment: Em um rápida pesquisa no google, encontrei várias respostas desse problema. Se você ja chegou a implementar poderia colocar o código para analisarmos.

Answer (score 2):

Vamos a lógica, para cada 1 cabeça existem 2 ou 4 patas.

> 2 patas = pato.
>   
>   4 patas = coelho.

Os números devem bater, por exemplo, não faz sentido ter 10 cabeças e 200 patas, afinal 10x4 = 40, sendo este o máximo possível de patas por cabeça.
Também existe a possibilidade mínima, pois 10 cabeças podem ter 20 patas.
As duas possibilidades sendo verdadeiras você pode continuar seu programa, falta implementar mais coisas, mas diria ser este um princípio, você precisa limitar para as possibilidades estarem dentro dos seus objetivos.

Fiz em C um teste básico, a lógica em qualquer linguagem é a mesma:

```c
int main(int argc, char** argv) {

    int totalCabecas;
    int totalPatas;

    printf("Digite o Total de Cabeças: ");
    scanf("%d", &totalCabecas);
    printf("Digite o Total de Patas: ");
    scanf("%d", &totalPatas);

    int testeMax = (totalCabecas) * 4; // 10x4 = 40, maximo de patas possiveis
    int testeMin = (totalCabecas) * 2; // 10x2 = 20, minimo de patas possiveis

    if ((totalPatas > testeMax) || (totalPatas < testeMin)) {
        printf("ERRO\n");
    } else {
        printf("OK!\nPossibilidade aceita\n");
    }

    return (EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Designando, respectivamente, por `numPatos`, `numCoelhos`, `numPes` e `numCabecas` os números de patos, coelhos, pés e cabeças, é fácil de ver que

```
2*numPatos + 4*numCoelhos = numPes
```

e que

`numPatos + numCoelhos = numCabecas`.

Resolvendo este sistema de equações lineares, chegaremos à seguinte solução:

```
numPatos   =  2*numCabecas-numPes/2
numCoelhos =   -numCabecas+numPes/2
```

---

Agora basta implementar a solução encontrada:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(){

    unsigned int numPatos, numCoelhos, numPes, numCabecas;

    cout << "Numero de pes: ";
    cin >> numPes;
    cout << "Numero de cabecas: ";
    cin >> numCabecas;

    numPatos   = 2*numCabecas-numPes/2;
    numCoelhos = -numCabecas+numPes/2;

    cout << endl
         << "Tem na sua cerca " << numPatos << " pato(s) e " << numCoelhos << " coelho(s).";

    return 0;

}
```